# MDX Result Count

Tags: mdx

I am a beginner in MDX queries. Can any one tell me how to get the record count that is a result of a MDX query?

The query is following:

`select {[Measures].[Employee Department History Count],[Measures].[Rate]} on columns, Non Empty{{Filter([Shift].[Shift ID].[Shift ID].Members, ([Shift].[Shift ID].CurrentMember.name <> "1"))}*{[Employee].[Business Entity ID].[Business Entity ID].Members}} on rows from [Adventure Works2012].`

I have tried various methods and I haven't really got a solution for that.

Comment: Could you please provide a reproducible example?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean row count when you talk of "record count", as MDX does not know a concept of records, but the result shown from an MDX query is the space built by the tuples on the axes.

I see two possibilities to get the row count:

- Just count the rows returned from your above query in the tool from which you call the MDX query.
- If you want to count in MDX, then let's state what you want to have:

You want to know the number of members of the set of non empty combinations of `[Shift ID]`s and `[Business Entity ID]`s where the Shift ID is not "1" and at least one of the measures `[Employee Department History Count]` and `[Rate]` is not null.
To state that different: Let's call the tuples like above for which the first measure is not null "SET1", and the tuples like above for which teh second measure is not null "SET2". Then you you want to know the count of the the tuples which are contained in one of these sets (or in both).

To achieve this, we define these two sets and then a calculated menber (a new measure in our case) containing this calculation in its definition,  and then use this calculated member in the `select` clause to show it:

```
WITH
SET SET1 AS
    NonEmpty({{Filter([Shift].[Shift ID].[Shift ID].Members, 
                       ([Shift].[Shift ID].CurrentMember.name <> "1"))}
              * {[Employee].[Business Entity ID].[Business Entity ID].Members}},
              {[Measures].[Employee Department History Count])
SET SET2 AS
    NonEmpty({{Filter([Shift].[Shift ID].[Shift ID].Members, 
                       ([Shift].[Shift ID].CurrentMember.name <> "1"))}
              * {[Employee].[Business Entity ID].[Business Entity ID].Members}},
              {[Measures].[Rate])
MEMBER [Measures].[MyCalculation] AS
       COUNT(SET1 + SET 2)
SELECT [Measures].[MyCalculation] ON COLUMNS
FROM [Adventure Works2012]
```

Please note:

- The sets `SET1` and `SET2` are not absolutely necessary, you could also put the whole calculation in one long and complicated definition of the `MyCalculation` measure, but splitting it up makes is easier to read. However, the definition of a new member is necessary, as in MDX you can only put members on axes (rows, columns, ...). These members can either already been defined in the cube, or you have to define them in the `WITH` clause of your query. There is no such thing as putting expressions/calculations on axes in MDX, only members.
- The `+` for sets is a union which removes duplicates, hence this operation gives us the tuples which have an non empty value for at least one of the measures. Alternatively, you could have used the [Union function](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/mdx/union-mdx?view=sql-server-ver15) equivalently to the `+`.
- The `Nonempty()` I used in the definitions of the sets is the [NonEmpty function](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/mdx/nonempty-mdx?view=sql-server-ver15), which is slightly different from the `NON EMPTY` keyword that you can use on the axes. We use one of the measures as second argument to this function in both set definitions.
- I have currently no working SSAS installation available to test my statement, hence there might be a minor error or typo in my above statement, but the idea should work.